# How to connect button and field value with jQuery for object in for loop from template

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

When I post form, any quanity updates with value from first quantity field. I don't know how to connect quantity value and particular submit button for this value.

My form in template.html

```
{% for item in cart %}
    <form action="{% url 'product_update' item.product.id %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id='quantity' value="{{ item.quantity }}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link update-product">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"> </span>
      </button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

My view (I use django-cart for my cart)

```
def product_update(request, id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    cart = Cart(request)
    quantity = request.POST['quantity']
    unit_price = product.price

    cart.update(product, quantity, unit_price)
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
```

My javascript

```
function updateProductQuantity(){
  $('button.update-product').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).parents('form')
    var quantity = $('#quantity').val()  //I think my problem is here
    $.ajax({
        'url': link.attr('action'),
        'type': 'POST',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'data': {
            'quantity': quantity,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
        },
        'success': function(data, status, xhr){
            alert(data['status']);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do:

```
 var quantity = $(this).parents('form').find('#quantity').val();
```

or more efficiently you can select the form itself. Ex:

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(){
    var link = $(this);
    var quantity = $(this).find('#quantity').val();
    $.ajax({
        'url': link.attr('action'),
        'type': 'POST',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'data': {
            'quantity': quantity,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
        },
        'success': function(data, status, xhr){
            alert(data['status']);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Your issue is you're saying "select the first "#quantity" on the page and get its value. Where you want to get the targeted forms #quantity's value.